# Белая страница продуктов категории Opencart

Tags: php, opencart

Пришел к Вам за помощью.
Случилась такая ситуация : на сайте стоит тема journal 3 , по словам товарища , которому помогаю , все работало отлично , но вдруг страница категории с товарами перестала открываться.
При том что при переходе напрямую на страницу товара все работает.
Обрыл всё, англоязычные форумы и наши.
Никаких ошибок в лог не записывает ,через pnp.ini і index.php  тоже ошибок словить не могу , их просто нету, на сервере в логах тоже пусто.
Третий день ломаю голову, может кто с таким сталкивался ?!
И да , с базой данных все ок.

Вот сайт:

https://caravan-auto.com.ua/

Comment: И чем мы вам помочь можем то?... Дебажить надо, а не сюда писать

Comment: Да вы прям "капитан очевидность". Написал же что во всех логах пусто и найти ошибки не могу.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701142/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-php-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5)

Comment: @МаксМороз Смотреть логи это не дебаг... [https://qna.habr.com/q/573757](https://qna.habr.com/q/573757)